# How do you pass data from one view to the other via react-router-dom without using url parameters?

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I use react-router-dom v 4.3.1 for client-side routing. I'm pretty new to React and can't figure out how to pass data from one view to the other without using url parameters.  In Angular, the Angular router has a data property where you can pass data associated with a route. An example would be:

`const appRoutes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'hero/:id',
    component: HeroDetailComponent,
    data: { title: 'Hero Detail' }
  },
];`

Can you do the same in react-router-dom? If not, how would you recommend I pass data in React?

Thanks in advance for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<Route path="hero/:id" render={() => <HeroDetailComponent title= "Hero Detail" />} />
```

Read this: [Pass props to a component rendered by React Router](https://tylermcginnis.com/react-router-pass-props-to-components/)

Or if you are using `<Link>` you can use pass through location object

```
<Link to={{ pathname: 'hero/:id', state: { title: 'Hero Detail'} }}>My route</Link>
```

Comment: Don’t use arrow functions inside component prop. That would create a new component every time. Use render instead if you want to pass props to the rendered component.

Comment: This seems to be what I'm looking for. Tested <Link> and that worked. 

And props to @jorbuedo for pointing that. According to the [Route official documentation](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/packages/react-router/docs/api/Route.md): "When you use component (instead of render or children) the router uses React.createElement to create a new React element from the given component. That means if you provide an inline function to the component prop, you would create a new component every render...When using an inline function ... use the render or the children prop."

Answer (score 0):

Well you Could use the context API to create a sort of global AppState that you could update in your first component and use in your second component.

You could also abuse the localStorage API by setting a key with the data in the first component and getting it in the other.

However both of these are workarounds that Shouldn't have to be used. Why do you want to redirect to a page but not pass data to it using URL parameters.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @ManavM. Yeah, I was thinking of using localStorage. The context API I have to read more on.

For this particular case, reason I don't want to use URL parameters is because of SEO. The product owner wants to use certain keywords in the url, and the ID I need passed is unfortunately not one of those keywords.

Comment: I see. Depending on the type of data it is, you might want to use context API instead. For example, if your data has anything that will not retain its previous form if serialised ( any class instance, like a momentJS date object, for example ). However, if it is just a bunch of primitives I suppose localStorage will work just as well.

Answer (score 0):

There'a several solutions. React being a library, not a framework, doesn’t force you into a single one.

One way is to use the context api. It’s like a link to an object shared between different components.

Another one is redux, which uses context underneath, and gives you a single store for the whole app. You changes values dispatching actions to the store, so it’s a bit tricky to learn the first time.

Using a stream library would open up a lot of different options, but it’s harder to get into. Check refract if you want to go this way.

A poor man’s stream approach that may serve you is using document as a bus to pass data arround, using addEventListeners to receive data and dispatch new customEvent to send it.

Next is the simplest one of all, share a simple object. Using imports form your components, you can import the same object on both and that will be a single instance where data can be shared. Simple JavaScript. It’s not the react way though, because changes won’t trigger a repaint on the component.